# My composer.json is missing

Tags: centos

I was installing composer on my system buy I run into a problem. when I type composer validate my console will output ./composer.json not found. Am I missing something? Should not this file be created when I install the composer?

This is the tutorial I was following, I am ussing CentOS7 https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Comment: When executing `composer validate` are you in the proper folder, where your project is?

Answer (score 0):

When executing `composer validate`, you need to be in the folder where your project is, as `composer` expects to find specific files in the folder where you execute it.

If you execute it globally, or from your home folder, (and not specifically a project), then it would not know which `project specific` settings to read, or what exact dependencies to install.